# using .deb packages in /var/cache/apt/archives

Tags: 11.10, installation, deb

I found all-deb-packages after downloading in /var/cache/apt/archives.And i am unable to use them on other systems.

For cheese software i found

"cheese_3.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb" and 
"cheese-common_3.2.0-0ubuntu2_all.deb".

i ran both the packages in my friend's laptop and both do not install cheese.

```
                HOW TO USE THESE PACKAGES??
```

Comment: Can you describe what commands you tried exactly?

Comment: dpkg -i cheese_3.2.0-0ubuntu2_i386.deb

Comment: @Newbi, and what was the output?  Unless there were errors given, that would install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install `.deb` packages directly (I assume you used `dpkg -i`) you need to make sure that you install also all dependencies because `dpkg` doesn't resolve dependencies automatically. I think this is probably the problem that you're having.

Besides this, in other answers to similar problems, I've seen [keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) being recommended. Maybe you should give it a try.

Comment: I copied my entire  /var/cache/apt/archives into my friends laptop(freshly installed ubuntu)and ran "dpkg -i *.deb" and all my apps were installed in his laptop.  I WANT TO KNOW IF THIS WILL HARM HIS OS.

Comment: It should be fine.  You may have downgraded or upgraded some versions of software.  Check out get-selections /set-selections for what you want to do.  Run an update cycle just to be sure.  If an auto update script is running it will clean up things.