# How to install some .deb packages from cache with apt?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies

I want to install `texlive-full` in my Ubuntu 20.04. It is a rather large download, and I have a metered internet connection.

I installed it in another computer running Xubuntu 20.04, and copied the packages from its `var/cache/apt`.

I can do `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`, but it will install all the dependencies explicitly (I don't want to have the dependencies explicitly installed), and it may also install other unwanted packages (because I copied all .deb packages from `var/cache/apt`).

How can I use `apt` to install `texlive-full`, so that it uses these .deb packages for dependencies instead of downloading them?

Comment: There is a similar question, whose answer really does not help (it also has a dead link). https://askubuntu.com/q/80128/124466

Comment: Just use regular `sudo apt-get update` && `sudo apt-get upgrade`. It should not download already existing packages, unless newer versions are available.

Comment: @mikewhatever This used to work in older versions of Ubuntu. In recent versions, it tried to redownload an existing package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To create a personal repository

Install dpkg-dev, type in a terminal

```
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install dpkg-dev
```

Create the Script to update your packages directory

It's a simple three liner:

```
 #! /bin/bash
 cd /var/cache/apt
 dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null | gzip -9c > Packages.gz
```

Cut and paste the above into gedit, and save it as update-debs in /bin.

Next, make the script executable:

```
 sudo chmod u+x /bin/update-debs
```

How the script works:

dpkg-scanpackages looks at all the packages in /var/cache/apt, and the output is compressed and written to a file Packages.gz, that apt-get update can read

Edited: =========================================================

Create a Ubuntu configuration file for the repository

```
sudo touch /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysources.list
```

Edit the empty file and add this line:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysources.list
```

And add this line:

```
deb [trusted=yes] file:/var/cache/apt ./
```

And you're done.

Whenever you put a new deb in the /var/cache/apt directory, run

```
sudo update-debs
sudo apt-get update
```

Now your local packages can be manipulated with Synaptic, aptitude and the apt commands: apt-get, apt-cache, etc.

Comment: I get this after running `sudo apt update`.


`E: The repository 'file:/var/cache/apt ./ Release' does not have a Release file.`

`N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.`

`N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.`

Comment: @Archisman Panigrahi: Edit the post, read the edit.